# AngularJS - Dynamically Load Javascript Snippets When Model Changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm hoping to load and unload javascript snippets dynamically when a model changes using ngSanitize.

Here's a demo showing what I'm trying to do:
http://jsbin.com/wenoz/5/edit?html,output

The logic goes like this:

```
* Store multiple snippets of JS in a database or string variables
* Load the JS into the DOM dynamically when the user changes an Angular model
* Remove any existing snippet in the DOM an instantiate the new snippet
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't completely get rid of javascript run when changing, once it executes it becomes part of the environment.  You could use an iframe to create a separate environment that doesn't have direct access to your page if that's what you want.  If all you want to to is run the scripts consecutively, you could just put it in an array and use ng-repeat on your script so it creates a new tag each time ([JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/dozeg/1/edit)):

```
<h3>A Demo to Dynamically Add/Remove Javascript with AngularJS</h3>
<button ng-click="setScript(one)">One</button>
<button ng-click="setScript(two)">Two</button>
<button ng-click="setScript(three)">Three</button>


<script ng-repeat="script in scripts" ng-bind-html="script"></script>


<script>
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
  app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.scripts = [];
    $scope.one = "alert('one')";
    $scope.two = "alert('two')";
    $scope.three = "alert('three')";
    $scope.script = '';
    $scope.setScript = function(script) {
      $scope.scripts = [script];
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This does work, but if a function contains an event listener, it'll fire as many times as the script has been loaded. http://jsbin.com/kuwed/1/edit

Comment: No way around that unless you want to use an iframe.